# Apply simplifier to arbitrary term

Tags: isabelle

I have a term in mind, say `"foo 1 2 a b"`, and I'd like to know if Isabelle can simplify it for me. I'd like to write something like

```
simplify "foo 1 2 a b"
```

and have the simplified term printed in the output buffer. Is this possible?

My current 'workaround' is:

```
lemma "foo 1 2 a b = blah"
apply simp
```

which works fine but looks a bit hacky.

What doesn't work (in my case) is:

```
value "foo 1 2 a b"
```

because `a` and `b` are unbound variables, and because my `foo` involves infinite sets and other fancy stuff, which the code generator chokes on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in feature AFAIK, but there are several ways to achieve this. You have already discovered one of them, namely state the term as a lemma and then invoke the simplifier. The drawback is that this cannot be used in all contexts, for example, not inside an apply proof script.

Alternatively, you can invoke the simplifier via the attribute `[simplified]`. This works in all contexts via the thm command and produces the output in the output buffer. First, the term must be injected into a theorem, then you can apply `simplify` to the theorem and display the result with `thm`. Here is the preparatory stuff that can go into your theory of miscellaneous stuff.

```
definition simp :: "'a ⇒ bool" where "simp _ = True"
notation (output) simp ("_")
lemma simp: "simp x" by(simp add: simp_def)
```

Then, you can write

```
thm simp[of "foo 1 2 a b", simplified]
```

and see the simplified term in the output window.

The evaluation mechanism is probably not what you want, because evaluation uses a different set of rewrite rules (namely the code equations) than the simplifier normally uses (the simpset). Therefore, this is likely to evaluate to a different term than by applying the simplifier. To see the difference, apply `code_simp` instead of `simp` in your approach with `lemma "foo 1 2 a b = blah"`. The proof method `code_simp` uses the code equations just like `value [simp]` used to.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `value` command, the evaluation of the argument is conducted by registered evaluators (see the [Reference Manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013-2/dist/Isabelle2013-2/doc/isar-ref.pdf) of Isabelle2013-2).

It used to be possible to explicitly choose an evaluator in previous versions of Isabelle (e.g., Isabelle2013-2) by giving an extra argument to the `value` command. E.g.,

```
value [simp] "foo 1 2 a b"
```

It seems that in Isabelle2014 this parameter was dropped and according to the [Reference Manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2014/doc/isar-ref.pdf) of Isabelle2014, the strategy is now fixed to first use ML code generation and in case this fails, normalization by evaluation.

From the [NEWS](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/e82c72f3b227/NEWS) file in the development version (e82c72f3b227) of Isabelle it seems as if this parameter will be enabled again in the upcoming Isabelle release.

**UPDATE:** As Andreas pointed out, `value [simp]` does not use the same set of simplification rules as `apply simp`. So even if available, the solution I described above will most likely not yield the result you want.

Comment: Thanks chris. I had expected `value [simp]` to work, and almost included it in my "list of things I've tried", so it's helpful to me that your answer addresses why that doesn't work.